# sofeware renderer. In this project, why the x,y,z axis like this?

Tags: c, 3d, coordinates, render, renderer

in this project (https://github.com/skywind3000/mini3d/blob/master/mini3d.c),when I try to change "model" and "view" matrix,I find the x axis pointing out of the screen，the y axis pointing left,and the z axis pointing up.

This is different from the left and right hand coordinate system.But I want to use left or right hand coordinate.How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer.

When use look_at function to build a "view" matrix,the "world-up" matrix should be {0,1,0,1} but not {0,0,1,1}.

you can see this answer:[Understanding glm::lookAt()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830340/understanding-glmlookat)